# How do I display the UTF-32 encoding of this character?

Tags: java, utf-32

I'm trying to display this [character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f0a1/index.htm):

Obviously I know I can display it simply by using `"\uD83C\uDCA1"` but I am creating a deck of cards and it would nearly impossible to display 2-Ace using this format without a really long comparison for all 52 cards. This is why I am trying to use the UTF-32 encoding for this character `0x0001F0A1` or `1f0a1` since the next card is just `0x0001F0A2` or `1f0a2`. I have tried using `Integer.parse()` and `Character.decode()` however neither has worked for me to get the actual glyph.

EDIT:
Just a small note, I am displaying this in a JOptionPane, I realize this isn't relevant, so I have the font set so its bigger and the user can actually see it...

Comment: A Java character is UTF-16, since that is UTF-32 it is two characters. Use a `String` like `String card = "";`

Comment: Interesting solution there thank you. It doesn't make it easier to shorten the long if-else statement I would need to find the right card, still thank you I didn't know I could do that! @ElliottFrisch

Comment: What long if-else statement? A short example might lead to a solution that eliminates the long if-else; without seeing it we can't help.